# invalid type argument of '->' C

Tags: c, types

I keep getting the error

```
invalid type argument of '->' (have 'int')
```

on the line I have marked with arrows when trying to read the contents of the input file from within a separate function.

It works if its kept in the main program. I realize it probably has something to do with the pointers but I cant work it out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void function1(file_a);

int main()
{

   FILE *file_a = fopen("input.txt", "r");

   if (file_a != NULL){

       void function1(file_a);
   }
   else{

   }

}

void function1(file_a)
{

   while(!feof (file_a)) <<<<<<<<
   {

   }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change to:

```
void function1(FILE * file_a);

///

    void function1(FILE * file_a)
    {

       while(!feof (file_a))
       {

       }

    }
```

Comment: Wow, nice asker/answerer usernames. :)

Comment: @NickVeys - I love this -- and the difference in camel case is great too.

Comment: Ha!  I did not see that.

Answer (score 5):

You didn't give `file_a` a type, so it defaulted to `int`, try this:

```
void function1(FILE* file_a);

...

void function1(FILE* file_a)
{
    ...
```

Comment: In addition note that "implicite `int`" rule was dropped since C99 Standard.

Answer (score 1):

Also, don't add the return type of the function you are calling. You only have to specify it when declaring/defining the function:

```
if (file_a != NULL){

       void function1(file_a); // <<< remove "void"
}
```